# model field not rendering on html page

Tags: python, html, django

> I want to show title or description on html page but i am not getting.
>   how can i do that ?

**models.py**

```
class Event(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField()
```

**views.py**

```
def get_event_list(request):
    model = Event.objects.all()
    return render_to_response('events.html', {'model':model})
```

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^events/get_event_list/$','events.views.get_event_list', name ='get_event_list' ),
```

**events.html**

```
<h4>{{ model.title }}</h4>
<p>{{ model.description }}</p>
```

Comment: Don't [delete your question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/39624244/1324033) just to reask it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are returning a list of objects. Not just one.

Try to loop it over.

```
{% for item in model %} 
    <h4>{{ item.title }}</h4>
    <p>{{ item.description }}</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Or update your view like:

```
def get_event_list(request):
    model = Event.objects.all()
    if model:
       model = model[0]
    return render_to_response('events.html', {'model':model})
```